# Time complexity of this code using Java 8 stream and predicate

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a map from which I am trying to retrieve data using Java 8 stream and a filter down using a predicate.

But I have huge doubts about the complexity of the code. Can anyone help me figuring out the time complexity of this code.

```
class Student{
   String id;
}
Multimap<Integer, String> map = HashMultimap.create();
    map.put(1, new Student("id1"));
    map.put(2, new Student("id1"));
    map.put(1, new Student("id2"));
    map.put(1, new Student("id3"));

// Time complexity of this ???
map.get(1).stream().filter(p -> p.getId().equals("id1"))
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: What do you think the complexity *might* be?

Comment: My guess is O(n)

Comment: As far as I can see, that code is `O(1)`, because there's no variable input.

Comment: @AndyTurner if there are multiple entries with the same hash code its going to be `O(logn)`, they are stored in red-black binary tree.

Comment: @Eugene there is no "`n`". All inputs are constant. It can't take anything but a constant amount of time.

Comment: @AndyTurner you are saying about *this particular piece of code* right?

Comment: @Eugene of course. That's what OP has asked, specifically: the code to create the map isn't otherwise relevant.

Comment: @Eugene "they are stored in red-black binary tree." No, they're stored in a `HashMap`, which has constant time retrieval. You're perhaps thinking of a [`TreeMultimap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultimap.html).

Comment: But isn't the "filter" method going to go through all the retrieved stream entries which will result in O(n) ?

Comment: The filter does nothing because streams are lazy evalutated and there is no terminal operation.

Comment: There's an enormous lesson here: worry about correctness first.  You're so caught up in worrying about the performance, you didn't even write a correct example.  Stream performance is fine.  Stop worrying, and focus all your brain cells on writing correct code.

Comment: @AndyTurner I was saying about how entries are stored inside a `HashMap` internally. And they *might* be stored in a tree if there are multiple hash code collisions (`TREEIFY_THRESHOLD` if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: I have edited the question. Sorry for the wrong example. I have added the terminal operation "collect" now.

Comment: That is a linear operation. What are your “doubts about the complexity”? What do you think, would be the alternative? What do you think, is the complexity of that alternative?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer for your **stream** code is O(1), because you have not specified a terminal operation and streams are lazy evaluated.  So at the moment your stream code does no stream processing at all.

The `map.get(1)` operation returns an already calculated Set. So the complexity is the one to find that entry: O(1), like one of the commentators already said.

After your edit it should be O (n).

But as Brian said think about correct code and not complexity.

Comment: But on that retrieved stream we are doing a "filter" which in worse case can go through all the entries isn't that going to be a O(n) operation ?

Comment: No you arent without a terminal operation like collect or so. You should provide a "complete" stream statement.

Comment: Edited the question. Added the terminal operation.